# Hyperlinks in macros all go to the same location!

Tags: hyperref

I must be doing something wrong that's really basic. Why do all my hyperlinks go to the first location, ie that of the FVR definition in the example below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[allcolors=blue,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}

% Whenever I use an acronym, I want it to link back to the definition:
\newcommand\FVR{\hyperref[FVR]{FVR}\xspace}
\newcommand\SWB{\hyperref[SWB]{SWB}\xspace}  
\newcommand\ABC{\hyperref[ABC]{ABC}\xspace}  

\section{Intro}
foo
\newpage

\section{Defs}
Here's where we define ``\textbf{def FVR}'' (\textbf{FVR}\label{FVR}) 
\newpage  some more text
\newpage  Here's where we define ``\textbf{ def SWB}'' (\textbf{SWB}\label{SWB})
\newpage  Here's where we define ``\textbf{ def ABC}'' (\textbf{ABC}\label{ABC}) 
\newpage

\section{Main}

This sentence with {\FVR}ish (FVR) \FVR and \FVR, looks okay \FVR.

This sentence with {\SWB}ish (SWB) \SWB and \SWB, looks okay \SWB but points to the wrong location

This sentence with {\ABC}ish (ABC) \ABC and \ABC, looks okay \ABC but points to the wrong location
\end{document}
```

Comment: you must add anchors for the links, e.g. in a current texsystem with `(\MakeLinkTarget{}\textbf{FVR}\label{FVR})` (in older you can use \phantomsection, that does more or less  the same).